# Solving a system of equations with inequalities and trigoniometry

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations

> Question, find the upper and lower bounds of $\text{P}$,$\text{Q}$ and $\text{S}$ when:
>
> 1. $$ \begin{cases}
>        \text{P}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\\
>        \text{Q}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\sin\left(\varphi\right)\\
>        \text{S}=\sqrt{\text{P}^2+\text{Q}^2}\\
>        0<\varphi\le\arccos\left(\frac{17}{20}\right)\\
>        \text{U}_{\text{Lf}}=230\cdot\sqrt{3}\\ 0<\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\le10
>        \end{cases} $$
> 2. $$ \begin{cases}
>        \text{P}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\\
>        \text{Q}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\sin\left(\varphi\right)\\
>        \text{S}=\sqrt{\text{P}^2+\text{Q}^2}\\
>        0<\varphi\le\arccos\left(\frac{17}{20}\right)\\
>        \text{U}_{\text{Lf}}=230\\ 0<\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\le16 \end{cases}
>        $$

---

My work, when I knew $\text{P}=7000$ instead of the boundaries of $\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}$, I solved it this way:

$$ \begin{cases}
    \text{P}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\\ \text{Q}=\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\sin\left(\varphi\right)\\
\text{S}=\sqrt{\text{P}^2+\text{Q}^2}\\
0<\varphi\le\arccos\left(\frac{17}{20}\right)\\
\text{U}_{\text{Lf}}=230\cdot\sqrt{3}\\
\text{P}=7000
\end{cases}\therefore
\begin{cases}
\frac{700}{69}<\text{I}_{\text{Lf}}\le\frac{14000}{1173}\\
0<\text{Q}\le\frac{7000\sqrt{111}}{17}\\
7000<\text{S}\le\frac{140000}{17}
\end{cases}$$

But for the ones above I do not get it.

Comment: You have asked the same question yesterday (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956976) and you have deleted it just after this "new" one was posted which is not a good practice at all.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I've deleted my question because I made a mistake in the question, so the answer wasn't right. So I thought, I asked it again but then the right way :)

Comment: It happens to everybody: you just have to correct your question. In any case refer to the old version **that should never be deleted** (answer deletion is another thing). Otherwise this site will become a jungle.

Comment: The way to fix a simple error in an equation in the question is to use the "edit" button, not "delete". Yes, you wasted a bit of effort someone put into trying to answer the question when it was wrong, but that effort is already wasted and the "delete" button does not bring it back.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, you're right. I'm sorry, next time I will do it the way it has to be.